# Database tables; spread them out, or null them together?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ddl, multiple-tables

Quick question regarding database design;

Given I'm storing `User` data in a database, I can identify two (*seemingly*) separate forms of data associated with a user; **account data**, and **profile data**.

Most profile data is optional, and unnecessary (*can, and often will be `NULL`*) whereas the account data is integral to the user, and their ability to use the service (*few or no records can/will be `NULL`*)

Is there any advantage to splitting this into two tables as a `1-to-1`? From merely a design perspective, it seems logical, but when talking performance is this a common (*good*) practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a logical design perspective an entity type is defined by the attributes it has. Each unique set of attributes defines a different thing and should go in its own table unless you have a good reason to do otherwise. Use design principles like Normal Form and the Principle of Orthogonal Design to verify which attributes belong in which table.

The advantage of doing that is that you don't need to create nulls or dummy values for attribute values which don't exist. Using nulls in that way almost invitably leads to errors, ambiguous results and compromises later on.

Answer (score 3):

i think it is common good practice to make separate tables for profile and account data. i have seen and used that style many times.

Comment: Thanks @i_forget - Where do the advantages lie though? For instance; if a user is created, a row is created in both the `Account` and `Profile` tables; the difference being that since only `Account` data is required (*and `Profile` data can be added later*) the `Account` row is populated with data, where as the `Profile` row is just a collection of `NULL` values. Should the `Profile` row remain uncreated until data is to be pushed into it, as to avoid a row that *could* remain permanently `NULL`'ed?

Comment: you wouldn't create the profile date entry until the user adds something for one and you can easily tell who/how many have profile data or not. you can add more profile data columns without impacting the crucial account table, if you need to have account info and innodb for the row level locking and transactions but also  want to make the profile data searchable you will be able to do that to since you can make use of the fulltext index on myisam...

Comment: I think the WHEN TO CREATE question is irrelevant. If you use a view with both tables OUTER JOINED, it will create by itself whenever you put data in the profile side.

Comment: Thanks @iDevlop - That's a very good point, which I'll implement. And thanks again i_forget.